# How to increase levels in cocos2d-android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

Currently i have made gameScene using cocos2d-android game engine, where all the functionalities of projectile and targets are included, in order to increase the levels upto 10 as speed increases, should i have paste all the code from gamescene to the next level screen? this becomes very lengthy procedure and will take more storage capacity, can somebody guide?

Answer (score 0):

Move levels data to separate resource file. When you have to load a level, read its data from this file and create your objects accordingly. Exact implementation details depend on your app specifics and are up to you.